How to prevent a selectable List from being updated when a confirmation dialog appears?
Let's us a selectable List as follows:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var elements: Set<UUID> = [.init(), .init(), .init()]
    @State private var selection: Set<UUID> = []
    @State private var isConfirmationDialogPresented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(
                elements.sorted(),
                id: \.self,
                selection: $selection,
                rowContent: { Text(String(describing: $0)).lineLimit(1) }
            )
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Button(
                        "Delete \(selection.count) element(s)",
                        role: .destructive,
                        action: { isConfirmationDialogPresented = true }
                    )
                    .disabled(selection.isEmpty)
                    .confirmationDialog(
                        "Delete \(selection.count) elements(s)",
                        isPresented: $isConfirmationDialogPresented,
                        actions: {
                            Button("Delete \(selection.count) element(s)", action: {
                                elements = elements.subtracting(selection)
                            })
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

When tapping the Button to display the confirmation dialog, the selectable List is reset (all selected rows become unselected, i.e. the selection value becomes an empty Set). How to prevent this?
Note: moving the .confirmationDialog to List causes the same behavior.
Tested with Xcode 16 beta 4 • iOS 18.

What do you mean with “reset”?

@JoakimDanielson When tapping the Button, the selection var is reset to its default value, i.e. an empty Set. All selected rows become unselected.

Can elements be an array instead? That way you can use the List's built-in delete feature by passing a binding of the array to List.

The issue is more than likely with elements.sorted(), id: \.self, this is sorting the screen anything the body is redrawn, and self should be replaced by a truly unique variable. put the sorted elements into a State so the list is stable.

I found that this only happens in edit mode. If you select some list rows then press the delete button, without pressing "Edit", the selected rows are successfully deleted. I'm not sure if this is intentional.
What I found to work is to pass the selected rows to the presenting: parameter. Apparently selection has not been cleared at the time when that is evaluated. Then you can access it using the closure parameter.
.confirmationDialog(
    "Delete \(selection.count) elements(s)",
    isPresented: $isConfirmationDialogPresented,
    presenting: selection, // <------ here!
    actions: { idsToDelete in
        Button("Delete \(idsToDelete.count) element(s)", action: {
            elements.subtract(idsToDelete)
        })
    }
)


If you want to maintain the selection after the confirmation dialog is dismissed, you can temporarily store the selection in another @State.
@State private var toBeDeleted: Set<UUID> = []

ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
    Button(
        "Delete \(selection.count) element(s)",
        role: .destructive,
        action: {
            isConfirmationDialogPresented = true
            toBeDeleted = selection
        }
    )
    .disabled(selection.isEmpty)
    .confirmationDialog(
        "Delete \(toBeDeleted.count) elements(s)",
        isPresented: $isConfirmationDialogPresented,
        actions: {
            Button("Delete \(toBeDeleted.count) element(s)", action: {
                elements.subtract(toBeDeleted)
            })
        }
    )
    .onChange(of: isConfirmationDialogPresented) { _, newValue in
        if !newValue {
            selection = toBeDeleted
        }
    }
}


Thank you, that's a good idea. Now the deletion works. However, when tapping on the delete button, all selected rows become unselected (the UI is automatically updated). Is this a bug?

@parapote Not sure if that is intentional or not. In any case I don't think it is something we can change. You can store the selected items in a separate @State, at worst.

@parapote My hypothesis is that when the confirmation dialog is shown, the list goes out of edit mode for a split second, then goes back into edit mode, hence resetting the selection. The same thing seems to happen when the confirmation dialog is dismissed.
